# log4j 1.2.x outputs JSON format

Tags: java, log4j

I just started working on a legacy code that uses log4j 1.2.x
The log works fine as is. It outputs the logs as String and the appenders work fine. However there is a need for us to change the output to JSON. I have tried changing the Layout to JSONTemplate and JSONTemplate layout, none of them gave the desired result.

Upgrading the version is not an option at the moment.

This is the current appender as configured at the moment

```
<appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p:%t  %c{4} %l - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

Can someone please point me to what I need to change to make this work.

Thank you

I have tried changing the Layout to JSONTemplate and JSONTemplate layout, none of them gave the desired result.

Comment: JSONTemplate simply do not exists in log4j 1.2, if you want something similar, you have to implent on your own ! When you read documentation in log4j site, be sure that there is no `2.X` in the URL.

Comment: I suggest you replace log4j with reload4j. Log4j 1.x is a) no longer supported, and b) vulnerable for several attacks. reload4j is meant to be completely compatible, including the same package names, but with the vulnerabilities fixed. It's also still supported. That said, you still have to right your own layout.

Comment: Your suggestions have been helpful. However, I think I need help with writing my own layout. I have checked https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html but I haven't really gotten a hang of it. Thank you.

Comment: "Upgrading the version is not an option at the moment": are you using Log4j 1.x anywhere in your **code**? Does replacing it with an old [`log4j-over-slf4j`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.6.0) version 1.6.0 replacement cause any linkage errors? If the answer to both questions is **NO**, you can redirect Log4j 1.x method calls to any modern logging back-end.